# Scanning words from file and saving them in an array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to scan words from a text file and then save them  in an array for the purpose of finding unique pairs of words (that is why I have structs here). This is only part of the assignment that I am working on.

The only error I keep getting is in this line:

```
  char* words[i] = malloc ( 10000 *sizeof (char));
```

The error is: variable sized object may not be initialized.

I dont know how to solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef struct {
    char word1 [50];
    char word2 [50];
    int frequency;
} pairs;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int x;
    int boolean = 1;
    int count = 0;
    FILE* f = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    while ( boolean != EOF) {
        char* words[i] = malloc (1000000 * sizeof (char));
        boolean = fscanf( f, "%s", words[i]);
        i++;


        for (x=0; x< i; x++) {
            printf ("%s", words[i]);
        }
        free(words[i]);
    } 
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code that it's hard to know where to start. `i` is an uninitialized variable, so what do you imagine `char* words[i]` does?

Comment: can you explain the significance of `10000` and `1000000`, and why you want to make a new array for each line instead of having one array that you add each line to?

Comment: @M.M What I want to do is scan the words from a file save these words in an array and allocate memory for that array. It is just a random big number to allocate memory for the words in the array. Did I misunderstand any steps here?

Comment: You should create your array before the loop. Currently you create it inside the loop, so it stops existing at the end of each loop iteration. Then you make a new array when you read the next line, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `words[i]` is of variable size because of the variable `i`. Therefore `char* words[i] = malloc ( 10000 *sizeof (char));` can not be used because if i.e. `i` exceeds the allocated memory this would lead to memory corruption, what the compiler prohibits.  You either have to use `char* words[10000] = malloc ( 10000 *sizeof (char));` or `char words[] = {a,b,...};` without any dynamic memory allocation (the compiler allocates the memory using the list)

Not `char words[];` but `char words[]={a,b,...};` with initialization list works

The solution is to typecast the pointer `malloc()` returns to `int`

```
char *words;
words = (int *)malloc(10000*sizeof(char));
```

See this **https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html#dynamic2D**

Comment: I tried    char words[10000] = malloc ( 10000 *sizeof (char));   and got an error: invalid initializer. I tried char words[ ] and got lots of errors including size of the array is missing.

Comment: `char words[10000] = malloc...` is an error, as is `char words[];`

Comment: @M.M what do you suggest then ?

Comment: nothing yet, there are many possible approaches to OP's task but none of them resembles the code posted so far.